# Hiding certain bookmarks from the awesome bar / autocompletion

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, awesomebar

In Firefox, I want to hide certain (not all!) bookmarks from the awesomebar / autocompletion on the address field. There once was an addon called "not awesome" that could do that, but it seems like it doesn't exist anymore. Any hint how to now hide entries from the awesome bar?

Comment: If you want to get better answers, then you might try accepting an answer on each of your other questions. Click on the outline of a checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer for a question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove individual sites from awesome bar auto-completion:

1. Cause it to show up in the auto-complete results.
2. Use the arrow keys to scroll down to the specific site.
3. Press <kbd>DEL</kbd> and the site will be removed from auto-complete's results.

This should work on all recent versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The article [notawesome](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/09/02/exclude-websites-from-appearing-in-the-firefox-address-bar/) discusses this problem, and lists all the possible solutions :

1. Use a separate browser for "private" sites.
2. Use a separate [Firefox profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing+profiles) for browsing "private" sites.
3. Use [Private Browsing](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Private+Browsing?s=private%20browsing) when browsing "private" sites (but then you
   can't bookmark the sites).
4. [Turn off bookmarks and/or history](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Options+window+-+Privacy+panel#Location_Bar) searching for awesome bar.
5. Use the [NotAwesome add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/notawesome/) if you can find it somewhere, as it seems to have been withdrawn.

Answer (score 0):

Another addon that work similarly is [HistoryBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/historyblock/?src=api). IT will block sites from showing up in the Firefox history which should in turn prevent them from showing up in the Awesome Bar via the history route.

I don't think it will necessarily block bookmarks from being shown on the Awesome Bar but perhaps you can use an alternate route to "bookmark" pages such as Furl or delicious.